# SOCKETIO: TypeError: object of type 'Packet' has no len(); Error while connecting to WebSocket: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, flask, networking, websocket

I am using SocketIO to connect a Python client to a Python Flask server. I am experiencing issues with the connection.The line, specifically, that is causing it is `self.sio.connect(socket_address)`

On the client end, I have the code:

```py
#socket.py
import socketio

class WebSocket():

    def __init__(self, socket_address):
        self.sio = socketio.Client()
        try:
            self.sio.connect(socket_address)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while connecting to WebSocket: {e}")
            print(f"Socket address: {socket_address}")
            raise e

#main.py:
from sockets import WebSocket as websock
ws = websock("ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket")
```

While on the server end, I have:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import eventlet

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

VOLUME = 0
CHANNEL = 0 
POWER = False
CURRENT_VIDEO = "./videos/video.mp4"

# New route for WebSocket connection
@socketio.on('remote-control')
def remote_control(data):
    global CHANNEL, VOLUME, POWER, CURRENT_VIDEO
    if data['event'] == 'power':
        POWER = data['value']
    elif data['event'] == 'channel':
        CHANNEL = data['value']
    elif data['event'] == 'volume':
        VOLUME = data['value']
    # Broadcast the updated settings to all connected clients
    socketio.emit('tv-settings', {'power': POWER, 'channel': CHANNEL, 'volume': VOLUME}, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5000)), app)
```

I'm seriously at a loss here. Apparently it has something to do with a `type Packet has no length with len(Packet)`

Here's the full traceback:

```py
Error while connecting to WebSocket: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Socket address: ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\g\Documents\Python\GenerativeVoice\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    ws = websock(hf.getSocketServer())
  File "c:\Users\g\Documents\Python\GenerativeVoice\sockets.py", line 12, in __init__
    raise e
  File "c:\Users\g\Documents\Python\GenerativeVoice\sockets.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.sio.connect(socket_address)
  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 276, in connect
    return getattr(self, '_connect_' + self.transports[0])(
  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\engineio\client.py", line 299, in _connect_polling
    r.status_code), r.json())
  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Server-side:

```py
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2023 20:48:16] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1690418894.4349656 HTTP/1.1" 500 490 0.006995
(41872) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 22442)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 588, in handle_one_response
    'eventlet.minimum_write_chunk_size', self.minimum_chunk_size))
TypeError: object of type 'Packet' has no len()
```

Also, here are my dependency versions to get everything working:

```
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1
python-engineio==3.13.2
python-socketio==4.6.0
Flask==2.0.3
Werkzeug==2.0.3
```

I have moved up 2 error codes since building the websockets. I have converted Flask to wsgi, and I even went into wsgi.py to try and debug, but it didn't seem to do anything. I've figured out the issue comes down to initializing the websocket. At that point it's out of my hands because it appears to be an issue with the dependencies.

My goal is to get the client to connect to the server. Ultimately I am trying to pass commands over through the back-end.

Could anyone provide any insight into this, and possibly some tips on how to debug it? Thank you so much.